# Раскраска частей мультимаршрута

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как раскрасить части мультимаршрута? От точки **A** до **B** один цвет, а от точки **B** до **C** другой.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap;
  var path_from = 'Киров, Ленина, 80';
  var path_to = 'Киров, Воровского, 135';

  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [58.599191, 49.648409],
    zoom: 12,
    controls: []
  }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
  });

  var trafficControl = new ymaps.control.TrafficControl({
    state: {
      providerKey: 'traffic#actual',
      trafficShown: false
    }
  });
  myMap.controls.add(trafficControl);
  trafficControl.getProvider('traffic#actual').state.set('infoLayerShown', true);

  var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: [
      'Россия, Кировская область, ' + path_from,
      'Россия, Кировская область, ' + path_to,
      'Россия, Кировская область, ' + path_from,
    ],
    params: {
      results: 1,
      avoidTrafficJams: true
    }
  }, {
    boundsAutoApply: true
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
  myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);

  multiRoute.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function(event) {
    multiRoute.getRoutes().each(function (route) {
      console.log('route data:', route.properties.getAll());
      route.getPaths().each(function (path) {
        console.log('path data:', path.properties.getAll());
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 93vw; height: 95vh"></div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать по примерам: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_access и https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options.
Если не получится, добавьте код, в котором возникли трудности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось как-то так... Есть что улучшить (сократить)?

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap;
  var path_from = 'Киров, Ленина, 80';
  var path_to = 'Киров, Воровского, 135';

  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [58.599191, 49.648409],
    zoom: 12,
    controls: []
  }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
  });

  var trafficControl = new ymaps.control.TrafficControl({
    state: {
      providerKey: 'traffic#actual',
      trafficShown: false
    }
  });
  myMap.controls.add(trafficControl);
  trafficControl.getProvider('traffic#actual').state.set('infoLayerShown', true);

  var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: [
      'Россия, Кировская область, ' + path_from,
      'Россия, Кировская область, ' + path_to,
      'Россия, Кировская область, ' + path_from,
    ],
    params: {
      results: 1,
      avoidTrafficJams: true
    }
  }, {
    boundsAutoApply: true,
    opacity: 0.9
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
  myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);

  multiRoute.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function(event) {

    multiRoute.getRoutes().each(function (route) {
      route.getPaths().each(function (path) {
        var index = path.properties.get('index');
        path.getSegments().each(function (segment) {
         switch (index) {
           case 0:
             segment.options.set({ strokeColor: '#FF0000' });
             break;
           case 1:
             segment.options.set({ strokeColor: '#00FF00' });
             break;
           default:
             segment.options.set({ strokeColor: '#0000FF' });
         }
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 93vw; height: 95vh"></div>
```

Comment: Как путь от A до B нарисовать поверх пути от B до C?

Comment: Вы можете построить два отдельных маршрута, добавленный на карту вторым будет сверху.